# I got an issue with database as Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: jmeter

Here is the screenshot for it [image: jmeter configuration what i done in tool]
[image: here is the scrrenshot for phpmyadmin database]

[[image: Got an error as cannot load jdbc driver[[3]]]

[image: here is the error i got]

I added everything but am getting error can anyone pls rectify where i did mistake ....!

Comment: Please post full error stack trace.

Comment: can u please suggest me a better solution for this@Mate Mrse

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your [JDBC Connection URL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html)

[image]

you need to replace `msql` with `mysql` and your configuration should start working as expected.

Also don't forget to restart JMeter after any .jar file added to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), the class loading is not dynamic unless you add the .jar on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

You might also be interested in [How to Automatically Pull Data from a DB for Your Performance Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-automatically-pull-data-from-a-db-for-your-performance-test/) article which explains how to use databases for JMeter tests parameterization.

Comment: and am getting an error like " Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)" @ Dmitri